# export javascript game to desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-engine

ok, so i´ve been playing around with html5 canvas and js and i wanted to know if it was possible to deploy a canvas game in desktop and mobile

i ask this because i´ve been doing a javaScript game engine project (more about practicing code and less about a real project...) build upon wrapping canvas into a UI.

in simple terms, i just want to build/export my game to android and desktop using javaScript or some king of library or framework and integrate it to my javaScript game engine project

Comment: for desktop there's [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). For mobile there's [Cordova/Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to export to PC, but I know "Phonegap/Cordova" that makes android app with html css js.

with android mobile phone, you can use "Droidscript" to make html apps.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: sort off... i already heard of them before, i am really trying to implement an export game option to my tool!

Comment: One thing you should know, droidscript need your money to build apk.